# Crons are running but System Status is No cron runs have been recorded

Tags: joomla, cron-job, cron, scheduled-job, status

Hosted (Linux) website on SiteGround + Joomla + CiviCRM

### Versions

PHP 7.0.29;
Joomla! 3.8.6;
CiviCRM 4.7.31

Scheduled jobs are administered as documented [Calling cron.php with curl](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#calling-cronphp-with-curl)

Cron jobs are running. One example:
[image: Version check cron job]

CiviCRM System Status page reports Cron not running,
[image]

Why this post?

There are several similar questions being posted without clear answers.
Support from hosting company is limited at this time on this issue.
No hints in the CiviCRM documentation.
I hope to get support from CiviCRM community.

My question: Why cron runs "are not being recorded"?

Comment: Emails are getting delivered automatically and fatch_bounce job is also executed with bounces visible in the mail report (via message delivery rate).

If I don't riderect the cron job's output to dev/null (while composing command in crontab) I am receiving Cron Daemon e-mails without any errors being reported.

Comment: I can verify execution of the jobs executed every hour via Scheduled Job Logs 
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Success (a:1:{s:9:"processed";i:0;})
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Success (a:0:{})
Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Success (1)

cPanel tools
Cron CPU Usage Statistics
Cron Memory Usage Statistics
Cron I/O Usage Statistics
Via cPanel tools I can verify that the cron jobs are executing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if the cron run is recorded if you call that url manually?
That way you eliminate the possibility of having a typo in the url or an invalid site key.

Some steps you could follow:

1. is 'curl' installed on the server that executes the cron run?
2. in the access log of your webserver, do you see the url being called?https://example.org/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php
3. when executing the command from a terminal, do you see an error, for example about an incorrect site-key?
4. do you see an error message in the website log? (I don't know where Joomla stores messages, in Drupal there is the Watchdog log)

Comment: (1) curl is installed and the full path to curl on Siteground is /usr/bin/curl
In the script I can use both curl or curl with full path.

(2) I have downloaded Raw Access Log file via cPanel
and I can find the logs related to cron.php in the following format:
<My IP address> - - [11/Apr/2018:16:00:01 +0200] "POST /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "curl/7.53.0"

(3) I didn't use the terminal. 
I would expect an error if the sitekey doesn't match. I don't get errors on execution.

(4) I can see similar cron.php related logs as above.

Comment: (3) Executed command from terminal curl --show-error --verbose --data ... No errors. Except if I test for non-existing data file just to check the difference.